# Can we search a MOSS parent site from a child subsite?

Tags: 2007, search, search-scope

I created a MOSS 2007 subsite and I need to enable searching in the parent site. Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have search configured, it is possible to search across sites.  The All Sites search scope will search against all sites indexed.  You can also identify other search scopes as needed that can filter down the index the query searches against.  This can be set based on the specific sites, or content properties.

If search is configured, you can go to the top level site of a site collection and go to the site settings page.  Under site collection administration (I believe) there is a a link called Search Scopes that enables you to set which scopes are available on that site.  The search settings page then lets you control the functionality of the search box within that site collection.  You can set the location for the full search center, and enable the search scope dropdown.